# Mapping United States Congressional Districts using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data for all congressional districts and want to generate a map of the USA at the congressional district level. I have a dummy data below and I want to map the "allocated" column. Is this doable in R using ggplot2 or any other package?

```
principal_place_state  principal_place_cd   allocated

Maryland                      04                 206.72510
North Carolina                05                -225.79786
NEW YORK                      00                 401.06613
Pennsylvania                  01                 65.81208
GEORGIA                       00                 408.43180
South Dakota                  00                 238.39864
```

Comment: It's doable using Several packages, but you need to have an additional dataset containing the boundaries of the congressional districts (I. E. A Shapefile or spatial polygons object). Do you have it?

Comment: No, do you know where I can get it?

Comment: Unless the congressional districts coincide with states, no, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the shapefile you need!

```
library(USAboundaries)
library(sf)

congress_sf <- us_counties(map_date = "2017-01-01", resolution = 'low')
```